# GNU make shell find certain path based on the pattern

Tags: windows, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to find all subdirectories of a folder that have the following path starting from a certain parent folder `[anything]/Component_[any sequence of character except '/' ]/Sources` using GNU make on a windows platform. The command I am using is :
`dirs := $(shell $(FIND) $(PROJECTROOT) -type d -regextype posix-extended -path '.*Component_[^\/]*\/Sources')` 
The **-regextype posix-extended** is optional. The default regex type or any regex type allowed by **shell** in **GNU make** can be used as log as it matches paths like this :

........../Component_ABC-00.01-...../Sources

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: The question here is why this `$(shell $(FIND) $(PROJECTROOT) -type d -regextype posix-extended -path '.*Component_[^\/]*\/Sources')` does not work. I already fixed it by be using `-regex` instead of `-path`.

Comment: I mean... it doesn't work with `-path` because `-path` doesn't accept regular expressions.  `-path` uses shell glob matching.  That's why both `-regex` and `-path` exist: they do different things.  As asked this question doesn't have anything to do with make or makefiles, it's just a question about how to use GNU find.

Comment: If you wanted to simplify your query you could use `find $(PROJECTROOT) -type d -path '*/Component_*/Sources'`

Comment: I tried this command : `find $(PROJECTROOT) -type d -path '*/Component_*/Sources'` before posting on stack overflow and it  doesn't work as it would get paths like `.../Componet_A/floder_1/Sources` and `.../Componet_A/floder_1/folder_2/Sources` and so on all of which are undesired paths. The only desired paths are for example : `.../Componet_ABC/Sources` , `.../Componet_def/Sources` , `.../Componet_xyz/Sources` and so on. Thank you for your efforts.